# Detecting how bright an image is

Tags: ios

For my app I use a user selected image as the background with the text above it blended in using kCGBlendingModeOverlay. It's fine on certain images, but the text isn't legible on a bright image. I know Apple use an algorithm in iOS 7 to change text colour based on the content below, but my question is how I would go about implementing it. I've searched around but haven't found anything relating to this so far. Does anyone have an idea about where I could start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use this grayscale calculation that weighs the colors the same way the human eye does, basically.
The eye has different sensitivity for the different colors, so N photons of green will appear brighter than N photons of blue.

```
 lColorIndex :=  ( (r * 77 + g * 151 + b * 28) shr 8 ); 
 if (lColorIndex < 130) then  
    ForegroundColor := clWhite       
 else
    ForegroundColor := clBlack;
```

This is only a pixel calculation, so you'd have to average over the area you're looking at (average R,G,B *before* the calculation of course)

Background:

The brightness we see is more or less:
v = 59% of the green, 30% of the red and 11% of the blue channel
= (30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b) div 100
which comes close to:
v = (77 * r + 151 * g + 28 * b) div 256
v = (77 * r + 151 * g + 28 * b) shr 8
which calculates faster in the computer world.

Comment: This answer is terribly inaccurate. Grayscale color *is not* brightness. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness. What you are describing is called *luminance*.

Comment: I stand corrected ;-) Not removing the answer though, it may still serve the OP.